# Using IIS Manager Users credentials for IIS FTP-server authentication in Windows server 2016

Tags: windows, iis, ftp, authentication

I'm a Linux guy, so this stuff is all new to me. For work I have to setup an FTP server. I'd like to setup some 'custom' login credentials other than the users that are on the domain. I read that you can use the "IIS Manager Users" to accomplish this.

Using the 'normal' logins available on the domain works fine, so the FTP server itself is working.

What I've done so far:

- Installed "IIS Management Service"
- Installed "FTP Extensibility" (read that it was needed, not sure if it is)
- Added users to the "IIS Manager Users"

On the FTP site:

- Under "FTP Authentication" disabled "Basic Authentication" and enabled "IisManagerAuth"
- Under "IIS Manager Permissions" added the users mentioned before.

I also tried adding those users under "FTP Authorization Rules".

Whatever I do, I can not login to the FTP server using the users that I have set up in "IIS Manager Users".

I must be overlooking something, but I can't seem to figure it out. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or know of documentation that explains how to get this done in server 2016?

Edit: The FTP server responds with "530 User cannot log in"

Comment: What exactly is the error you got (client log or IIS FTP log)?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, should've mentioned that. It's a "530 User cannot log in".